# CSS Margin between div

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a very simple html code but I don't understand where is the problem.

I have this code:

```css
.margin {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="margin">Test test</div>
  <div class="margin">Test test</div>
  <div class="margin">Test test</div>
</div>
```

So I would like a margin of 20px between the divs. 
But in fact the browser just enter only 10px between the divs.

How it's possible? Someone can help me?

Comment: You are setting the margin as 10px thats why you have 10

Answer (score 0):

it is normal, the default behavior of the "margin" property. the margin takes the max of the margin between the two div

use `margin:20px` if you want a margin of 20px between the div

Answer (score 0):

It is merging the two margins. I'd recommend using something like:

```
.margin {
  margin: 20px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

margins of adjacent elements collapse - only the greater one of the two will apply, the other one is ignored. See my example.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.margin1 {
  margin: 10px;
}
.margin2 {
  margin: 20px;
}
.margin3 {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="margin1">Test test</div>
  <div class="margin2">Test test</div>
  <div class="margin3">Test test</div>
</div>
```

If you want to have 20px between your DIVs, do it as follows:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.margin {
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.margin:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="margin">Test test</div>
  <div class="margin">Test test</div>
  <div class="margin">Test test</div>
</div>
```